# is useAnimatedGestureHandler still valid with react-native-gesture-handler in 2023

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am concerned about the proper way of using react-native-gesture-handler, the documentation says that Gesture Handlers are deprecated and I should be using GestureDetector, the context is that I need to combine gestures, and when I try to do it this way

```
  const gesture = useMemo(() => Gesture.Tap().onStart(() => {}), []);
  const gesture2 = useAnimatedGestureHandler<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent>({
    onStart: () => {},
  });

  const combined = Gesture.Exclusive(gesture, gesture2);
  return (
    <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
      <Animated.View style={styles.button} disabled={disabled} android_disableSound>
        <Animated.View style={styles.ripple} />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{children}</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </GestureDetector>
  );
```

this is a no-go because I get a red underline under gesture2 saying

```
Argument of type 'OnGestureEvent<PanGestureHandlerGestureEvent>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Gesture'.ts(2345)
```

Is there still a valid use case for useAnimatedGestureHandler or should I consider it deprecated?

Thanks